# Iterator over Vector class (array)

Tags: c++, static-libraries

These iterator in the collection classes confuses me. I got a Map with key of string, and value being a Vector class (similar to an array). As i understand it my iterator variable `it` is assigned to the map. So i should be able to to get it´s value and assign it to a new Vector class so I can read it´s contents or know it´s size etc... but how do I do this?

```
for (Map<string, Vector<string> > :: iterator it = array0.begin();
                                         it != array0.end(); it++)
{
    Vector<string> arr = it; // Error
```

Comment: Are you really using the [Stanford C++ libraries](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/materials/cppdoc/)?  Because as far as I can tell, [their Map class](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/materials/cppdoc/Map-class.html) does not have member functions `begin()` nor `end()`.

Comment: Yes but I think older versions of the library don´t have it.

Comment: Just a guess, but I think in the Stanford libraries it iterates over the keys, not the values. So you need something like 'Vector<string> arr = array0[*it]'. Posting the error message might help, or perhaps asking someone at Stanford?

Comment: The stanford C++ libraries do not have begin, end, or iterators: http://www.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106b/cs106b.1126/materials/cppdoc/Map-class.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your Map is a std::map, the elements of a map are pairs of (key,value), so the value is the second element of the pair:

```
Vector<string> arr = it->second;
```

Comment: @TomLilletveit: It is the second element of the pair.